# Alexa doesnt send request with AMAZON.StopIntent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Alexa doesnt send an **IntentRequest** containing the **AMAZON.StopIntent** if i try to invoke it using my echo device or the service simulator. I tried to invoke it using the **common utterances** listed [here](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/standard-built-in-intents.html#available-standard-built-in-intents), but i never get a request. It only makes my echo device stop listening. Instead i would like to send out a response containing an outputSpeech saying 'Good Bye' and shouldEndSession set 'true'.

However, as soon as i start a new Session, my skill receives a **SessionEndedRequest** with the **reason** saying "**USER_INITIATED**".

It also doesnt work using the Service Simulator, typing in the common utterances i provided.

It also doesnt make a difference if i put sample utterances equals the common utterances.

Any ideas?

[edit] the skill is in german

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have `AMAZON.StopIntent` defined in your interaction model. Did you confirm that you have something like the following your interaction model?

```
{
   "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
   "samples": []
}
```

Comment: It is defined by default, since it is a required intent.